# How do I spell "So! So! So! So! So!"?

Tags: words, spoken-language

I've heard people say "So! So! So! So! So!" (or possibly "Sou! Sou! Sou!" or maybe using "z" instead of "s" - I'm bad at hearing) when laughing in agreement.

[When middle-aged women speak Japanese](http://rurousha.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/when-middle-aged-women-speak-japanese.html) gives an example of this:

```
Oishii! (Or any other word from the options supplied below.)
So desu ne!
So so so so so!
So ka!
Ne?
Ne!
[continues on - too long for this question]
```

How is is spelt? Is it the same as the そう that's used in そう です? I tried searching for 然う然う然う然う然う (apparently 然う is a rarer, kanji form according to [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86&eng=&dict=edict)) but couldn't find anything.

Comment: 私なら「そーそーそー！」「そうそうそう！」のどっちかかな・・・

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the そう of そうです yes. That is it. No deep meaning, nothing.

Comment: +1 for a "straight to the point" answer. There really is no other meaning behind what the person is saying.

Comment: -1 because the question was mainly about spelling/orthography of this phrase, and you haven't really touched on it. If this appeared in a book or manga, would it be written そうそうそうそうそう, or would some of the そうs be abbreviated to そ to indicate the fast speed? Would any commas be used? Here is an [article](http://homepage3.nifty.com/fwjd1945/column/2000-02-19.html) which makes a point of writing it as そそそそそ, but I don't know if it's representative of the general approach among most authors. I would like to see a reply which quotes from a book or something.

Comment: Your article is about someone questioning the japanese language based on his own opinion because we do write it そう. And telling a beginner that そう can written そ would be as well a real bad move.

Comment: I didn't say, and the article doesn't say, that そう can be written そ in general. I was asking whether そうそうそうそうそう can be written そそそそそ (or whether it might have commas etc!) You can't dismiss this just by saying そう is the correct way to spell そう. The phrase 「そっか‥‥‥」 (meaning exactly そうか) exists with that spelling, and doesn't imply that そう can be pronounced or written そっ in other contexts.

Comment: @Hyperworm: I agree with you that this does not answer the question being asked, but the asker accepted this answer, which means that he is satisfied with it.  So I am not sure if it is worth arguing whether this answer is appropriate or not.

Comment: @Hyperworm FWIW, I was wondering how to write it in a tweet. If anyone has any English-language links on そうそうそう, they're welcome. I accepted fairly promptly because I was worried someone might say it's too basic or too google-worthy.

Comment: @oldergod Btw is this allowed? : "そうそうそうそう。". Or do we have to put a full stop after every "そう" ?

Comment: What is that you call a full stop? a 。? But yes, you can write "そうそうそう".

Comment: `.` is a full stop in the UK, a period in Canada or the US. `。` is... something else, but here is considered close enough to be called the same way (as it apparently serves basically the same purpose in Japanese orthogrpahy as `.` does in English orthography).

Answer (score 1):

This repeated そう are kind of [aizuchi 相槌](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aizuchi). 
It might be regarded as a [backchannel](http://www.cs.utep.edu/nigel/bc/) also. (I'm not a linguistic expert.)

As you may know, native Japanese often use the combinations of verbal and non-verbal backchannels like そうそう／うんうん and nodding during the conversation.
[This small study](http://sachikoide.com/Mister_O_Corpus_KaoriKobayashi.pdf) shows some numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is そう and means yes or yeah

Answer (score 0):

"そう、そう、そう" implies strong agreement and affirmation with the remark of the other.

To me, it's very different from simple and curt "そう."
She is saying "It's really delicious" and demanding affirmation of the other on her statement and judgement.

We usually and casually say "そう、そう" in agreement, but don't repeat "そう" so many times.

But she repeated it four times. She must have felt it really, really, really, and really delicious.

By the way, we don't apply Kanji character, 然 to そう. 然 is used for the words such as "然しながら" meaning "but, however"、"然く" meaning "like that," and a part of nouns such as 自然、天然、黙然、憤然、歴然、端然、恬然、豁然、公然、昂然、浩然、and etc.

Just for your amusement though I understand it's off-topic, the degree of shock you get every time you fail in the entrance exam of Tokyo University is descibed as;

淡然　in the first challenge

冷然　in the second challenge

凝然　in the thid challenge

唖然　 in the fourth challenge.

? in the fifth challenge.